# MariaDB: Can't create table, errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've been trying to build a database for a side-project of mine, but I can't seem to fathom the notion of foreign keys creation. Here is my code (I would be more than grateful if you could take a look):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meeting (
meeting_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
period_no varchar(10) NOT NULL,
session_no varchar(10) NOT NULL,
meeting_no varchar(10) NOT NULL,
date DATE NOT NULL,
chair_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
agenda_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (chair_id) REFERENCES mp (mp_id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (agenda_id) REFERENCES agenda (agenda_id)
)engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS agenda (
agenda_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
special boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
meeting_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
speech_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (meeting_id) REFERENCES meeting(meeting_id),
FOREIGN KEY (speech_id) REFERENCES agenda(speech)
)engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS speech (
speech_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
body text, 
mp_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (chair_id) REFERENCES mp(mp_id)
)engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mp (
mp_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
chair_in_meeting_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL,
speech_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (chair_in_meeting_id) REFERENCES meeting(meeting_id),
FOREIGN KEY (speech_id) REFERENCES agenda(speech)
)engine=innodb;
```

The process stops at the first table. I thought there should be a specific order of creating the tables with their primary keys and then alter them by adding the reference for the foreign keys, but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

MariaDB version is: 10.0.29-MariaDB SLE 12 SP1 package

EDIT:

> ---
>
> ### LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> 2017-03-10 14:55:03 7f3180ae5700 Error in foreign key constraint of table `politikoslogos`.`IF`:
>   Create  table `politikoslogos`.`IF` with foreign key constraint failed. Referenced table `politikoslogos`.`mp` not found in the data dictionary near 'FOREIGN KEY (chair_id) REFERENCES mp (mp_id),
>       CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (agenda_id) REFERENCES agenda (agenda_id)
>   )engine=innodb'.

Comment: it seems there exist multiple errors in your script. but still, which statement of the scripts caused this error?

Comment: @RavinderReddy I just updated the post with more on the error. It seems that the statements on the Foreign Key declaration on the first table is causing the problem.

Comment: In the agenda table: `FOREIGN KEY (speech_id) REFERENCES agenda(speech)` - you're setting a foreign key to reference the table its in. You're also looking for a field that doesn't exist (agenda.speech) for that key.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski Ooops :P Good eyes! Thanks for noticing.

Comment: From the meeting table the agenda is refered and vice versa. What is the sense in that, refering both table to each other? If you try to establish a many to many relationship you need an extra table.

Comment: @Myonara Not many to many, but 1(meeting) to many(agendas). My thought was, because a meeting will have at least one agenda, each agenda should have the ID of its meeting. But, I could see that being the error of my schema... I will try it with out it and see if that works. Thanks

Comment: 1 to many means that the agenda needs the reference to meeting, but not the meeting...

Comment: You mean that the agenda should be referenced in the meeting table, right?